# How to make my php mvc native can run in the web hosting

Tags: php, web, web-hosting

how should i put MVC project in the hosting

This is my MVC project folder structur.

[image]

This my index.php file[image]

And this is the file manager inside web hosting
[image: File Manager in the hosting]

Comment: I would think `public` should be `public_html`. I don't see `mvc` here though.. is this laravel framework?

Comment: @user3783243 sorry i have change into bigger image now, i have try to put all folder and file inside public folder in public_html but it turn error 500 page doesn't found

Comment: `Error 500` does not means page not found, it surely means `Fatal PHP error` in your case. It means part of your code do not run in that webserver. To know the exact error you should check the file contained in `/logs/domainname.error.log` (or similar name, where _domainname_ represents your domain name)